# Name must be unique for items of type: Component within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict

Tags: tridion, content-porter-2009

I have this weird situation where I am trying to import a component (which is a shared item from parent publication) from prod environment to dev environment.

Situation:

**Prod:** In child publication - component is shared and has title as "prodcut_details"

**Dev:**  In child publication - Component is a Local Item and has title as "prodcut_details"

While Import in progress, I get the following error:

```
Tridion.ContentManager.UniquenessException: Name must be unique for items of type: Component within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources  of conflict: tcm:12-1234.
```

Can anyone help here ?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard Tridion behaviour. The Content Porter will try to create a shared item within the child publication on the DEV environment and then it finds an item with the same name and it will throw the uniqueness exception.

You could just rename the local item on dev and then run the import.

Did you know there's a separate [Tridion stack exchange](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/)? 
You'll have more luck asking questions over there...

Comment: Yaa, I got it fixed. Also I ll use the Tridion Stack Exchange next time. Thanks alot.